# VisualStudioCode on Windows with WSL Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, task, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just updated to Windows 10 1809 and is trying to run VSCode with the WSL Ubuntu. I have deleted the legacy WSL distro and installed "Ubuntu" from Microsoft Store.

Now in VSCode, I have set the "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe", and I can open a terminal by "New Terminal". However, when I tried to run the build task, instead of running the "make", it prints out the help information from the ubuntu.exe.

Any one has any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, it seems something was wrong with my WSL installation that the bash.exe were gone. I re-installed the WSL and it came back and now it works!

Answer (score 2):

The May, 2nd 2019 announcement of "[Remote Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development)" proposes an official support with:

[**Visual Studio Code Remote - WSL**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl)

[image: https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-remote-release/images/wsl-readme.gif]

> The Remote - WSL extension extension lets you use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as your full-time development environment right from VS Code.
>
> This new, optimized support lets you:
>
> - Use Windows to develop in a Linux based environment, using Linux specific toolchains and utilities.
> - Edit files located in WSL or the mounted Windows filesystem (e.g. /mnt/c).
> - Run and debug your Linux based applications on Windows, in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe",
```

Comment: Well, I used to use that with the legacy WSL distro, but after I delete the legacy distro, that file does not work anymore. And with the Ubuntu distro, the terminal opened is the ubuntu.exe now.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems something was wrong with my WSL installation that the bash.exe were gone. I re-installed the WSL and it came back and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to idanp's answer,
I have the latest Ubuntu from the windows store and use this line now in settings.JSON to target the WSL bash on my win10 vscode:

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"`